# I am running two Nvidia GeForce 9600 GSO's and want to run 3 monitors with Win 10.

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

However I don't have the SLI bridge to connect them together.  Both of the cards are using the standard DVIx2 connections on the back but when i connect the third monitor it isn't seen.

What am I doing wrong?  I don't game anymore and so don't need any performance boost from the SLI bridge.

I have older monitors that don't have display port or HDMI connections so I HAVE to keep the DVI cabling.

Comment: what do you mean by "it isn't seen"?

Comment: I have all three plugged in and it only sees two

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 video cards installed, you should be able to run 2 displays off of the first card and the 3rd display off the second card.

First thing to check for troubleshooting is the display adapters in Device Manager.  Navigate to:

Control Panel >  Hardware and Sound > Device Manager

and check to see if both cards are listed.  If your motherboard supports SLI, you may need to ensure that your BIOS is not configured for it since you don't have the SLI bridge.  Then, make sure you have the latest nVidia GeForce display drivers installed:
[GeForce Driver v342.01](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/112594).
I would advise using the nVidia Control Panel to configure your displays instead of the Windows display settings for more advanced setups like yours since it has more options.

Comment: I will check into this and see if this fixes the issue - thanks.  Didnt even think that the BIOS might be the issue.